# SAS: logical problems in if statement condition

Tags: sas

TL;DR: Why doesn't the code below return a True for the 'checkhigh'?

I have a list from which I am trying to create a table of counts that satisfy certain criteria. It wasn't working and in troubleshooting I've come across this and I'm stumped. Two test cases, level = 0.7 with high/low +-0.1, the second one same but with a high of +0.2. The first case should satisfy the if statement:

if level = low+0.1 and level=high-0.1 then do;

but it doesn't. When I break it down further, the "level = low+0.1" is returning True, but the "level=high-0.1" is not when it should. What am I doing wrong?

```
data ex1; 
  input id $ level $ high $ low;
  cards; 
t1 0.7 0.8 0.6
t2 0.7 0.9 0.6
; 
run; 

data table1; 
    set ex1 (keep= id level high low);
retain
checklow 0
checkhigh 0
;

if level = 0.7 then do;
    lowcheck = low+0.1;
    highcheck = high-0.1;
    if level = low + 0.1 then checklow = 1;
    if  high = level + 0.1 then chechhigh = 1;
    if level = low+0.1 and level=high-0.1 then do; ahhhh = 1; count = count+1;end;

end;
run;
```

Comment: Btw - you have a typo in your example (it doesn't affect the result, but) - `chechhigh` is there in the assignment step.

Comment: There is some digit precision issue when comparing numbers.    try: if  round(high, .1) = round(level + 0.1, .1) then checkhigh = 1;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to the joys of floating point arithmetic.

In decimal arithmetic, using a fixed (non-infinite) number of decimal places, it's trivial to show that 2/3 != 1-1/3, and 2/3 + 1/3 != 1, unless you round.  That's because 1/3 is not representable exactly; it's a repeating decimal.

In binary arithmetic, 1/10 is similarly not possible to represent exactly.  (In fact, only negative powers of 2 are; 1/3, 1/5, 1/10, etc. are all impossible to represent exactly.)  As such, you have the risk of inexact matches.  In floating point arithmetic, `equals` is *always* dangerous when using decimals - even ones that look "normal" in decimal representation.

Instead, you have `fuzz` and `round` available.  `fuzz` eliminates trivial differences away from integers (but doesn't work if your comparison is two non-integers); `round` of course rounds off to a smaller point which should eliminate trivial differences even of non-integers.

In your case, `round` is the way to go:

```
data table1; 
    set ex1 (keep= id level high low);
retain
checklow 0
checkhigh 0
;

if level = 0.7 then do;
    lowcheck = low+0.1;
    highcheck = high-0.1;
    if level = round(low + 0.1,.1) then checklow = 1;
    if  level = round(high - 0.1,.1) then checkhigh = 1;
    if level = low+0.1 and level=high-0.1 then do; ahhhh = 1; count = count+1;end;
  put level= low= high= checklow= checkhigh=;
end;
run;
```

Comment: The variable checkhigh is retained. So checkhigh will be 1 forever from the time when the condition is true. Though it is not related with the floating precision.

Comment: That is (of course) also true, and good to point out, though not related to the question at hand.  I assumed this was just a toy example and not completely showing what the OP is doing.

Answer (score 0):

You are very probably struck by floating-point rounding problems. The numbers you manipulate cannot be represented exactly by the machine. You can find an explanation there (for python, but I suppose it is the same for sas):
https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

In practice, you can either use integers instead of floating points (if all your numbers are multiples of 0.1 or 0.01, for instance), or define a small tolerance epsilon, and replace tests for a = b by (a > b - epsilon and a < b + epsilon).